# Hashed Password Check Issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a Forgot-Password system where users are emailed a **ForgotKey** code to enter to access a reset password screen.  When this **ForgotKey** is entered into the database, it is hashed.  I used a similar system for my signup page and it's working correctly.  I copied most of the code over from that system and now I am getting an error that the user's inputted password does not match the hashed password in the database.  Am I using the correct **password_verify** code for this scenario?

```
        $Email = $_SESSION['PWResetEmail'];
        $ForgotKey = $_POST['ForgotKey'];
        
        $ForgotKeySQL = "SELECT Email, ForgotKey, ForgotTime, UserID FROM UserTable WHERE Email = ?";
        $ForgotKeySTMT = $conn->prepare($ForgotKeySQL); 
        $ForgotKeySTMT->bind_param("s", $Email);
        $ForgotKeySTMT->execute();
        $ForgotKeyRESULT = $ForgotKeySTMT->get_result(); // get the mysqli result
        while ($ForgotKeyROW = $ForgotKeyRESULT->fetch_assoc()) {                           
            // A: If password matches DO NOT hash, then send user back to forgot.php to retry
            $ForgotKeyCheck = password_verify($ForgotKey, $ForgotKeyROW['ForgotKey']);
            if ($ForgotKeyCheck == false) { // <----- code is failing here
                $ForgotKeySTMT->free_result();
                $ForgotKeySTMT->close();
                header("Location: ../forgot.php?4"); 
                exit();
            }
            // A: If password matches hash, then let user pass to next step of forgot password system.
            else if ($ForgotKeyCheck == true) { // <---- I want this line to be true
                $ForgotTimeFINAL = $ForgotKeyROW['ForgotTime'];
                $UserIDTemp = $ForgotKeyROW['UserID']; 
                $_SESSION['UserIDTemp'] = $UserIDTemp;
                $_SESSION['ForgotKey'] = $ForgotKeyROW['ForgotKey'];
                
                $ForgotKeySTMT->free_result();
                $ForgotKeySTMT->close();
                header("Location: ../forgot.php?3"); 
                exit();
            }
            else {
                $ForgotKeySTMT->free_result();
                $ForgotKeySTMT->close();
                header("Location: ../forgot.php?2");
                exit();
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Why do you use a `while` loop? There can't be multiple rows for the same email, can there?

Comment: And if there are multiple rows, that could be the problem. Different rows could have different `ForgotKey`, and you're reporting failure if the first one doesn't match.

Comment: `$forgotKeyCheck` can only be `true` or `false`. What's the `else` block supposed to be for?

Comment: Have you tried to print each variable and compare them visually to rule out that first? Do you get visually same strings?

Comment: The extra else was copied from another file.  I thought that the columns would be put into an array and that would use ROW.  Do I not need row?  What else should I use?

Comment: The code appears to be correct. Either way, questions "please look at my code, it doesn't work for some reason" are a deliberate off topic, as being vague and uncertain. You are supposed to debug your code line by line to find the problem yourself. See a crude instruction on debugging https://www.phpdelusions.net/basic_principles_of_web_programming#debugging